# Prove commutative of entanglement of two natural numbers.

Tags: natural-numbers, operations-research

I have defined an operation for entanglement of two natural numbers.
It is: $a$ T $b$

---

Example part 1 of 3:

$$
13 \\
24 \ \ \ \
$$
$$1 * 4$$

---

Example part 2 of 3:

$$
13\\
24
$$
$$1 * 2 + 3 * 4$$

---

Example part 3 of 3:

$$
13\\
\ \ \ \ 24
$$
$$3* 2$$

---

Sum all results:

$$
(1 * 4) + (1 * 2 + 3 * 4) + (3 * 2) = 4 + 2 + 12 + 6 = 24
$$

---

Example part 1 of 3:

$$
24 \\
13 \ \ \ \
$$
$$2 * 3$$

---

Example part 2 of 3:

$$
24\\
13
$$
$$2 * 1 + 4 * 3$$

---

Example part 3 of 3:

$$
24\\
\ \ \ \ 13
$$
$$4* 1$$

---

Sum all results:

$$
(2 * 3) + (2 * 1 + 4 * 3) + (4 * 1) = 6 + 2 + 12 + 4 = 24
$$

---

How to prove that this operation is commutative ?
From example, it seems that it is, but have no idea how to prove it.

---

From example: $a$T$b$ = $b$T$a$, where $a = 13$ and $b = 24$

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Given two natural numbers $n,m$ how do you define $n*m$?  Or is it $nTm$ you are trying to define?  Not much is clear here.  surely it can't depend on how you write them on the page?

Comment: And if you are trying to demonstrate commutativity...well, it's hard to understand why you'd take an example where the two factors were the same.  Whatever binary operation you have in mind, $nTn=nTn$, right?

Comment: Sure, maybe I did wrong example

Comment: @lulu Now it should be more clear

Comment: Ok, so in each case just flipping the picture (moving the lower term to the top) gives you a valid step for the opposite operation without changing the value.  this proves commutativity.  If you write out the steps for $20\,T \,13$ then you'll see this simple correspondence between the stages.